# Processing each row of a table in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I havve following table in a form.

```
      <form id="eForm" action="">
                <table class="fMain" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody>        
              <tr class="ist">
                  <td>In work</td>
                  <td>09/25/2013</td>
                  <td><input type="text" value="3500.00" name="salesS" id="totalS" class="fo" readonly=""></td>                
                  <td ><input type="text" value="23.00" name="cusS" id="cusS" class="form-field-tiny readonly" readonly=""></td>
                  <td>0.66%</td>                                         
              </tr>
               <td>In work</td>
                  <td>09/25/2013</td>
                  <td><td id="salesS" style="tar">$345.00</td></td>                
                  <td id="custS" style="tar">$223.00</td>
                  <td>0.66%</td>                     
              </tr>                             
             </tbody>
           </table>
          </form>
```

In my jquery section I am using following code to iterate throw each row.

```
 $('.fMain').each(function () {
                var num = document.getElementById('totalS').innerHtml;
                var cNum = document.getElementById('cusS').innerHtml;
                alert(num);
                alert(cNum);
                formatCurrency(num, cNum);
            });
```

When it runs I can see .each going through the number of rows but for some reason the values for num and cNum are same as the first row. 
What is wrong here? Help me fix. Thanks

Comment: `$('.fMain').each(function () {` you are actually looping through each table here, not each row of a table....

Comment: Can use $('tr').each(function(){
   alert($("#totalS").val());    
}); Refer http://jsfiddle.net/U2Gt3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `class` attribute instead of `id` for `input` tags

```
    <form id="eForm" action="">
            <table class="fMain" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>        
          <tr class="ist">
              <td>In work</td>
              <td>09/25/2013</td>
              <td><input type="text" value="3500.00" name="salesS" class="totalS fo" readonly=""></td>                
              <td ><input type="text" value="23.00" name="cusS" class="cusS form-field-tiny readonly" readonly=""></td>
              <td>0.66%</td>                                         
          </tr>
          <tr> <!-- missing tr tag here -->
           <td>In work</td>
              <td>09/25/2013</td>
              <td><td id="salesS" style="tar">$345.00</td></td>                
              <td id="custS" style="tar">$223.00</td>
              <td>0.66%</td>                     
          </tr>                             
         </tbody>
       </table>
      </form>



$('.fMain tr.ist').each(function () {
            var num = $(this).find('.totalS').val();
            var cNum = $(this).find('.cusS').val();
            alert(num);
            alert(cNum);
            formatCurrency(num, cNum);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.getElementById('totalS')` which will select only element with given id, use `this` to get current row.

```
this.innerHTML;
```

Comment: You mean this.('totalS') like that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you get it by id. In html you shouldn't have many elements with the same id. Browser just returns first which find to you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly correct your HTML markup, all tags are not closed properly

Secondly use only one jquery or javascript as your choice

**Jquery Solution**

```
$('#eForm table tr').each(function () {
            alert($('#totalS').val());
            alert($('#cusS').val());

             //your processing here
    });
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/pxdqW/)

Answer (score 0):

- Use `.value` not `innerHTML` to get the `<input>` value:

  var num = document.getElementById('totalS').value;
  var cNum = document.getElementById('cusS').value;
- Also your table is missing one `<tr>` and has a `<td>` inside a `<td>`. It looks like invalid markup to me.
- use this to get a object array of rowrs: `$('.fMain tr')` not just `$('.fMain')`

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
$('#eForm table tr').each(function () {
         var ts = $(this).find('#totalS').val();
});
```